# how to open a word documents in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I have a Microsoft word document contained some texts, images and equations (40 pages)
I want to create a flutter app for reading this document.
I have tried to convert this document to html format by using save as a webpage on Microsoft word, but the app not loading these files (use the plugin [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)).
And I have tried to convert it to markdown format (plugin [flutter_markdown](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_markdown)), but the app not loading the images and equations.

what is the best way to create an app reading this file?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to achieve this using [flutter_filereader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_filereader) package

Comment: the Example Demo can't work in Android. when open a file, a loading icon keeps showing, no any step operation.
and i read in the View/report issues than Playstore Rejects it  (https://github.com/fluttercandies/flutter_filereader/issues)